# MYSQL finding common values on name column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a mysql table with a field `name` which might have common entries like below

```
name
---
abc
abc.com
```

I want to select all common values and i have written the query below:

```
select * from table
group by name having count(*) >= 2;
```

Here, name is basically server hostname. So, as per definition, I need to compare only the first value before `.` 
So, `server` is same as `server.abc.com`
I am getting 0 rows selected which doesn't look correct

Comment: Are abc and abc.com considered duplicates?

Comment: You need to elaborate on your definition of "duplicate" because `abc` and `abc.com` are not normally considered the same values

Answer (score 0):

To your RDMS, these are not duplicate values. The database is comparing matching strings, and `'abc' != 'abc.com'`. What I assume you want is to check for multiple urls, regardless of the top level domain (`.com`, `.org`, etc). To do this, we can grab the URL before the final period.

```
select 
  substr(
    name
    , 0
    , locate('.', reverse(name))
  )
  , count(*) 
from 
  table
group by 
  substr(
    name
    , 0
    , locate('.', reverse(name))
  ) 
having count(*) >= 2;
```

The code above will disregard the domain, but you may still have issues with subdomains (`news.abc.com`, `videos.abc.com`, etc) or protocal indicators (`http`, `https`, etc). I will leave those as an exercise for you should you need them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question i created a query may be it will help you.
since you did not shown proper database structure, i created same scenario in a table and created query as per that.
Eg:

> select count(c1.city_name) as totals from city c1  inner join city c2 
>   on c1.city_name LIKE CONCAT('%',  c2.city_name, '%') group by
>   c1.city_id having totals >1;

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, this work for oracle

```
select * from(
SELECT a.name, count(b.id) duplicates  FROM  table a,table b 
WHERE a.name LIKE CONCAT(b.name, '%')
group by a.name
) where duplicates >=2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select name, count(name) 
  from (select substring(name, 1, 
               if(position("." in name)=0,
                 length(name),
                 position("." in name)-1) 
               ) name
         from table) t1
  group by name 
  having count(name) >= 2;
```

if you want all entries, remove "having count(name) >= 2"